# Android Studio - Firebase existing child is getting deleted, when try to update the value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a specific child Value in Firebase, with the help of below code. But instead of getting updated, the existing child is getting deleted.

I have gone through similar kind of questions, nothing worked for me. Any help would be highly appreciated.

please find code which i tried to update and also find the firebase screenshot.

```
reffortask=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("taskmanagement").child("new");

 timeStamp=getIntent().getStringExtra("tTimeStampTask");
 userName= getIntent().getStringExtra("tUserName");
 String updatet =taskUpdate.getText().toString().trim();
    if (userName!=null) {
        updatedby = "Updated by " + userName + " on " + currentDate + ":- " + updatet;
    }

private void updateTask(){ 
        HashMap<String,Object> updateTask = new HashMap<>();
         updateTask.put("remarksTask",updatedby);
        if (timeStamp!=null){
        reffortask.orderByChild("timeStampTasK").equalTo(timeStamp)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot childTask = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
            String taskKey=childTask.getKey();
            final HashMap<String,Object> updateTask = new HashMap<>();
            updateTask.put("remarksTask",updatedby);
            String last =""+childTask.child("remarksTask").getValue();
            lastUpdate.setText(last);
            reffortask.child(taskKey).updateChildren(updateTask)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                   Toast.makeText(EditTask.this,"Remarks Updated ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a value gets deleted that means that either you're calling `removeValue()` on that property, or you are write `null` to it. Given the code you shared, the latter seems most likely.

So it seems like `updatedby` is `null` in this code:

```
updateTask.put("remarksTask",updatedby);
```

You might want to verify this by logging the value right before this line of code, or protect against this by putting an `if (updatedby != null) around it.

---

Unrelated: your code seems a bit overly complex, and non-idiomatic. I'd write the same functionality as:

```
reffortask.orderByChild("timeStampTasK").equalTo(timeStamp)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    DataSnapshot childTask = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
    DataSnapshot childRemark = childTask.child("remarksTask");
    String last = childRemark.getValue(String.value);
    lastUpdate.setText(last);
    childRemark.getReference().setValue(updatedby).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
           Toast.makeText(EditTask.this,"Remarks Updated ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
  }
  ...
```

The differences:

- Limit the query to at most one result, since your `onDataChange` handles only one result anyway.
- Get the current value of `remarksTask` with `getValue(String.value)`. This will give a better error message if you ever have the wrong type in the JSON.
- Set the value of the property directly with `childRemark.getReference().setValue(updatedby);`, instead of building a map with only a single value in it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion, as you mentioned "updatedby"  String was giving a null value. its working fine now